# Fragment PopBackStack() issues

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got an android app with a ListView Navigation Drawer that is capable of opening a couple of different fragments. I am running into an issue where I am allowing the user to click to open a fragment, even if it is the fragment currently displayed. (This functionality is necessary)

Here is my logic to open Fragment B if the list item is clicked:

```
FragmentB fragmentB = FragmentB.newInstance();
transaction = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentB);

if (lastClicked == Constants.FRAGMENT_B) {
    ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}

transaction.addToBackStack("FragmentB");

try {
    transaction.commit();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {}

lastClicked = Constants.FRAGMENT_B;
```

This code works fine until I click to open the fragment that is currently open. Notice the code to pop the backstack so that the current fragment is finished and a new fragment of the same type is opened.

So here is where the issue is:
Say I click Fragment A, Then click Fragment B, Then click Fragment B again. Between the time that the backstack is popped to remove the old fragment b and add the new fragment b, Fragment A's onCreateView and onResume are both run. How can I avoid fragment A from loading while the new instance of fragment B is being created?

Thanks!

---Edit---
Posted solution below. This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out myself. Here it is in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

```
Fragment oldFragmentB = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentB");
FragmentB fragmentB = FragmentB.newInstance();
transaction = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

if (lastClicked == Constants.FRAGMENT_B && oldFragmentB != null) {
    transaction.remove(oldFragmentB);
    transaction.add(R.id.container, fragmentB, "FragmentB");
    transaction.disallowAddToBackStack();
} else {
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentB, "FragmentB");
    transaction.addToBackStack("FeedFragment");
}

try {
    transaction.commit();
} catch(IllegalStateException e) {}
```